# Is there a way to find a good/best/near-best approximation $p(x)\cdot\exp(-a\cdot x)$ ($p(x)$ is a polynomial) to a function $f(x)$?

Tags: exponential-function, approximation, approximation-theory, gamma-distribution

In my work I often encounter functions with somewhat exponential decay, usually they are non-negative and non-zero everywhere and of even symmetry (so let's just assume $x\ge0$ for simplicity). I would be nice to have a robust way to find the best or near-best approximation
$$
f(x) \approx e^{-ax}\sum_{i=0}^nb_ix^i .
$$
Best or near-best in the sense that $n$ is small. I can think of some ways to get *an* approximation, but no systematic robust idea.

I'm very much familiar with polynomial approximations in every shape or form (e.g. Chebyshev polynomials), as well as approximations by sums of exponentials (e.g. Prony's method). I couldn't find anything when looking for related keywords (e.g. approximation by gamma pdfs, exponential polynomials) when a "combination" of both is used.

Is there something like this and/or what could I look for?

**EDIT:**
I found a modified Prony's method in http://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/plonka/pdfs/gamm-preprint.pdf and currently checking if this would work. For simple cases this seems to already work fairly well, and now I'm working to get it robust for more complicated cases.

**EDIT 2:**
Seems like the same as the normal Prony's method the modified one is not really robust, even with only one exponential factor.

Comment: "even symmetry"...  Maybe you want $\mathrm{e}^{-a|x|} \cdots$?

Comment: Do you have values of $f$ for $x$ near zero? for negative or positive $x$ of large magnitude? (either, since the function is described as having even symmetry)  Is your data about values of $f$ "noiseless"?

Comment: @EricTowers: f is noiseless. I have data everywhere (I have a "blackbox" function though). I clarified the even symmetry remark by just looking at x>=0 for now.

Comment: Btw I know that I could do some things analytically (e.g. Laplace transform, then rational approximation, the inverse Laplace), but I need a numerical way.

Comment: Would you consider nonlinear regression as a solution ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No, I don't think so. Main argument would be it isn't guaranteed or robust in finding a good/best/near-best solution. And it's slow.

Comment: @oli Is $a$ a continuous parameter, or is it limited to a number of specific discrete values? If the latter, roughly how many different values of $a$ are relevant to the use case?

Comment: FIRST PART OF MY COMMENT : 

On a purely theoretical viewpoint I think that there is a way, thanks to the method which general principle is explained in this paper : 
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . 

But the case of function $f(x)=e^{-ax}p(x)$ with degree $n$ polynomial is not explicetly treated in the paper. The integration allows to eliminate the exponential term and leads to a polynomial equation of higher degree but which is linear with respect to the coefficients of the powers of $x$. This would need more studies for practical application.

Comment: SECOND PART OF MY COMMENT : However I am affraid that would not satisfy your requirement. For each different power $n$ of the polynomial the integral equation is different and the implementation of matrix calculus will be different. So you will not get a general code usable in every cases as expected. I'm very sorry to disappoint you.